# Migrating from API V1 to V2: How to getPaymentInstuctions after capture order?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I'm trying to migrate from API V1 to V2 in PHP. In V1, you could use this code to get further payment-instructions after executing a payment:

```
try {
    $execution = new Paypal\Api\PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId($sPayerId);
    $payment = \Paypal\Api\Payment::get($sPaymentId, getApiContext());
    $payment->execute($execution, getApiContext());

    $payment = \Paypal\Api\Payment::get($sPaymentId, getApiContext()); // re-fetch payment with payment-instructions
    if ($payment->getPaymentInstruction())
    {   $sBankName = $payment->getPaymentInstruction()->recipient_banking_instruction->bank_name;
        $sBandAccountNumber = $payment->getPaymentInstruction()->recipient_banking_instruction->international_bank_account_number;
    ...
    }
}
catch(PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
...
}
```

It's important for us to display the payment-instructions to our customer: If they use the "pay later"/"pay via invoice"-feature, they need to know to which bank and account to transfer the money to.

In API V2, you use this code to capture an authorized order:

```
$request = new PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCaptureRequest($sOrderId);
try {   
    $response  = getClient()->execute($request);
}
catch(PayPalHttp\HttpException $exception) {
    ....
}
```

So what are the next steps to get the payment-instructions now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field was not documented for the v1/payments API.

For v2/checkout/orders , a `payment_instruction` field is documented as an order creation [request field](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body) (within purchase_units) and [response](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-response) field.

A similar field exists when [capturing an authorization](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#definition-capture_request).

---

For [Pay Upon Invoice](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/apm/pay-upon-invoice/integrate-pui-merchant/#link-createanorder), there is a `processing_instruction` field.

In all these cases, the fields do not contain information regarding "which bank and account to transfer the money to" or similar.

However, for PUI there is a response field `payment_source.pay_upon_invoice.deposit_bank_details` . Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```json
{
  "id": "5O190127TN364715T",
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "processing_instruction": "ORDER_COMPLETE_ON_PAYMENT_APPROVAL",
  "payment_source": {
    "pay_upon_invoice": {
      "birth_date": "1990-01-01",
      "name": {
        "given_name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe"
      },
      "email": "buyer@example.com",
      "phone": {
        "national_number": "6912345678",
        "country_code": "49"
      },
      "billing_address": {
        "address_line_1": "Schönhauser Allee 84",
        "admin_area_2": "Berlin",
        "postal_code": "10439",
        "country_code": "DE"
      },
      "payment_reference": "b8a1525dlYzu6Mn62umI",
      "deposit_bank_details": {
        "bic": "DEUTDEFFXXX",
        "bank_name": "Deutsche Bank",
        "iban": "DE89370400440532013000",
        "account_holder_name": "Paypal - Ratepay GmbH - Test Bank Account"
      }
    }
  },
  "purchase_units": [
    ....
  ],
  "links": [
    ....
  ]
}
```